# Displaying temperature symbol

Tags: avr, atmega, temperature

I am trying to output degree centigrade symbol from atmega2560 from serial port. I looked up at ascii table. The ascii code it said was 167. When I tried it there was another symbol instead which I can't show here. After doing little bit of research, I tried 0167+248. It displayed '○' instead of '°'. Other posts said that Alt + 167 works but could not find ascii code for Alt. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to output degree centigrade symbol from atmega2560 from serial port. I looked up at ascii table. The ascii code it said was 167.

The format of the extended ASCII table (symbols from 127 to 255) depends on the code page that is used.

> When I tried it there was another symbol instead which I can't show here.

You should figure out on what code page you are currently working. Like ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) for example.

> Other posts said that Alt + 167 works but could not find ASCII code for Alt.

What they meant is to press the ALT key and enter 167 on the numpad. This prints the character on position 167 (decimal) from the current code page.

Remember that the ASCII value that is send from the micro controller is just interpreted on the receiver side according on its code page.

Comment: additional note: beside the interpretation on the receiver side of course it is important to know that you actually sent. which code page did you use in your code editor. if you used unicode source files then your compiler may be configured to use a specific code page to that it converts the string literals.

Comment: I am using avr studio 4. How can I make adjustments in this compiler ?

Comment: You can not adjust code page or file format within AvrStudio4. But you don't have to. As long as your character is part of your code page and is one byte wide (ASCII+extended) you just need to know the numeric value. Then you could type it in the editor using the ALT-value combination. The compiler will translate this to the respective value again, while the terminal program will then convert it back when receiving it. If editor and terminal code page match, you see the same char.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer

```
U+2103
Image

Server-generated
℃
Decimal Escape

&#8451;
℃
Hex Escape

&#x2103;
℃
UTF-8
```